# Making websites which display TeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, big-list

I am currently trying to make a website, and would like to upload some of my notes on the webpage itself as well as as pdfs. The basic example of this is the Stacks Project.

**Question:** What are your favourite website template hosts, or ways of coding websites yourself, that allow for LaTeX to be displayed in-webpage?

Obviously the ideal would be having support of most TeX functions like TikZ, as well as being able to directly copy and paste my LaTeX code (or have it uploaded automatically) with minimal changes required.

Comment: What do you mean "allow for LaTeX to be displayed in web-page"? Support for displaying math formulas or something else?

Comment: https://www.mathjax.org/#docs

Comment: @Stephen I mean supporting displaying most things that LaTeX produces, including maths formulas, TikZ diagrams, etc.

Comment: For full LaTeX functionality maybe you could use https://texlive.net/ made by @DavidCarlisle.

Comment: The Stacks Project is made using [Gerby](https://gerby-project.github.io/) which anyone can use. Another website using Gerby is [Kerodon](https://kerodon.net/)